# Ionic2 pull to refresh function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs, ionic3

**news.html**

*refresh function*

```
  <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content pullingText="pull to refresh">

    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
```

*get news list from server*

```
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'news'">
      <ion-card>
          <ion-item-group (click)="goToNewsDetail(new)" text-wrap *ngFor="let new of news">

            <ion-thumbnail *ngIf="new.Preview_image1" item-start>
              <img src="{{new.Preview_image1}}">
            </ion-thumbnail>

            <ion-card-content>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-card-title>{{new.title}}</ion-card-title>
                <p>{{new.news_category}}</p>
                <h3>{{new.publish_time}}</h3>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-card-content>

          </ion-item-group>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-list>
```

**news.ts**

```
  doRefresh(refresher){

    console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      refresher.complete();
    }, 1500);

  }
```

*get news data*

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public newsData:NewsDataProvider){
    this.getNews();
  }
  getNews() {
      this.newsData.getNews().then(data => {
        this.news = data;
      });
  }
```

I want to refresh news list and get new news list from server. This code I get from ionic2 doc, but it's not working fro me

Edit:
This is what I added in **news.ts**, no error showing but after do refresh no news list coming out.

```
  doRefresh(refresher){

    this.getNews().then(() => {
      refresher.complete();
    });

  }

  getNews(): Promise<any> {
      return this.newsData.getNews().then(data => {
        this.news = data;
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried by placing a call to your `getNews` method inside of the `doRefresh?`

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public newsData: NewsDataProvider){
    this.getNews();
  }

  getNews(): Promise<any> {
      return this.newsData.getNews().then(data => {
        this.news = data;
      });
  }

  doRefresh(refresher) {
    this.getNews().then(() => {
      refresher.complete();
    });
  }
```

**EDIT**

After debugging the code, we found out that the service was keeping a local copy of the data:

```
getNews() {
    if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('servertrj.com/api/news/index/…').map(res => res.json().data).subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        resolve(this.data);
      });
    });
  }
```

That's why when the pull to refresh tried to get the new data, the same list of items was returned by the service. Replacing that method by the following should work:

```
  getNews() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('servertrj.com/api/news/index/…').map(res => res.json().data).subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        resolve(this.data);
      });
    });
  }
```

Or instead of creating a new promise like that, you can use the `toPromise` operator from RxJS:

```
  getNews(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get('servertrj.com/api/news/index/…')
                    .map(res => res.json().data)
                    .toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: I edited information in the question, check please. Thanks!

Comment: Is it necessary I upload whole coding in the question?

Comment: Can you place a `debugger` right before the `this.news = data;`, to inspect what does the `data` property have?

Comment: Wait a mins, I will upload whole my code here.
Because I think this not 'data' problem, getNews function can show news list for me, but just cannot refresh

Comment: Ok. Is the refresher being showed up in your view when you pull down?

Comment: Refresher showing, but function not working, no new news coming out when I added news from backend

Comment: But you can see that the `getNews()` method is being called when you pull to refresh, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151330/discussion-between-sebaferreras-and-yuyang-he).

Comment: Thanks a lot.. perfect solve my problem...
The problem is provider there.

Comment: How can I get this below code
`doRefresh(refresher) {
    this.getNews().then(() => {
      refresher.complete();
    });
  }`
as _Observable_ instead of **promise**